# Multiple strings to one string comparison bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a `shell script` like below. It works based on a condition that if `$table` contains `test` then executes `small.sh`, elde `big.sh`.

```
if [[ "$table" =~ "test" ]]
then 
  echo "events"
else
  echo "history"
fi
```

Now I want to check if tables contains `test` , `_test_and_results` and `success` in `if [[ "$table" =~ "test" ]]`.

How can I do that

I have tried like below

```
if [[ "$table" =~ "test" && "$table" =~ "success" ]];
then
    echo "events"
else
    echo "history"
fi
```

But when I pass table name `abc1_success` It is printing `history` instead of `events`.

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should use 'or' instead of 'and'. Ie || instead of &&.

Your current script is true only if both test and success are found.

Answer (score 6):

`abc1_success` does not contain `test`, `_test_and_results` and `success`.

It only contains `success`.

It sounds like you wanted "or" instead of "and":

```
table="abc1_success"
if [[ "$table" =~ "test" || "$table" =~ "success" ]];
then
    echo "events"
else
    echo "history"
fi
```